# WebView on iOS keeps displaying shadow on my inputs

Tags: ios, css, webview

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 and a WebView to display a form in my iOS app (iOS 8.0). However, despite all my attempts, the default textfield shadow keeps being displayed in my HTML form.

Here's what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK2WP.png

Notice the shadow at the top of the field? My  fields don't have it, only input text and textarea.

Here's what I already tried (in CSS3):

- Added -webkit-appearance: none - did not work; nothing changed
- Tried outline:none, border: none, background:none, box-shadow:none

And here's my corresponding CSS:

```
textarea, input, select {
  outline: none;
  border: thin solid #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 0px,
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of the shadow?